# Remove focus of system window

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to print the document currently displayed in the control.
I use `WebBrowser` and `Print()` function to that.
But after using `Print()` function there is a system window which pops up and gets focus of my application.
In addition I can not go back to the form unless I close the system window.

Is there any chance to let me remove the focus of this system pop-up window?

Comment: Please, share your code so far. Actually, you can try to suppress browser popups

Comment: I only have a button in my code. After clicking this button I would like to print the currently displayed document.
        
`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            webBrowser1.Print();
        }`

But as I said, the system window appears and I would like to remove the focus from that window without exiting it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ShowActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showactivated(v=vs.110).aspx) property on Window object so you can set the main window not activated after you show a child window.

From MSDN:

> When a window with its ShowActivated property set to false is opened, the window is not activated and its Activated event is not raised until a user manually activates the window by selecting it.